# render image link as image in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

I am using a `textarea` to get information from users.
I want to add a feature to the `textarea` where they will be able to add an external image link hosted on another website and display the image and not the image link on in the `textarea` content submitted.

This is an example of what I want...

> This is a text from textarea, and images are rendered properly like
>   below.
>
> [image: This is the image]

So far, this is what I have tried and throwing error.

```
To add an image, put the link like this: <br/>
   <span>http://res.cloudinary.com/wisdomabioye/image/upload/v1470139046/404_zx728k.png</span>
```

```js
var result = document.getElementById('result');
btn = document.getElementById('button');

btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
// adding new line here
var content = document.querySelector('textarea').value;
 var finalText = content.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>');
  
 // I want to use jQuery or Vanilla JavaScript to get the text content of the span element and do something like this
 var link = finalText.find($('span')).text();
 
 finalText += "<img src='"+ link +"'/>";
 
 result.innerHTML = finalText;
  


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   
 <br/>

<textarea cols=33 rows= 10 > </textarea>


<input type="button" value='submit' id="button">


<div id="result">  </div>
```

The error is

```
error{
  "message": "Uncaught TypeError: finalText.find is not a function",
  "filename": "http://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 32,
  "colno": 23
}
```

Comment: What error do you see on console?

Answer (score 0):

find() is an array method, and finalText is a String.

This is a quick solution that I've found.

```js
var result = document.getElementById('result');
btn = document.getElementById('button');

btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
// adding new line here
var content = document.querySelector('textarea').value;
 var finalText = content.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>').replace('span>', 'img src="').replace('</span', '"');
 result.innerHTML = finalText;
  


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   
 <br/>

<textarea cols=33 rows= 10 > </textarea>


<input type="button" value='submit' id="button">


<div id="result">  </div>
```